# Haskell parMap performance?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I was trying to bench parMap vs map with a very simple example:

```
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Criterion.Main

sq x = x^2

a = whnf sum $ map sq [1..1000000]
b = whnf sum $ parMap rseq sq [1..1000000]

main = defaultMain [
    bench "1" a,
    bench "2" b
  ]
```

My results seem to indicate zero speedup from parMap and I was wondering why this might be?

```
benchmarking 1
Warning: Couldn't open /dev/urandom
Warning: using system clock for seed instead (quality will be lower)
time                 177.7 ms   (165.5 ms .. 186.1 ms)
                     0.997 R²   (0.992 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 185.1 ms   (179.9 ms .. 194.1 ms)
std dev              8.265 ms   (602.3 us .. 10.57 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 14% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking 2
time                 182.7 ms   (165.4 ms .. 199.5 ms)
                     0.993 R²   (0.976 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 189.4 ms   (181.1 ms .. 195.3 ms)
std dev              8.242 ms   (5.896 ms .. 10.16 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 14% (moderately inflated)
```

Comment: Square is almost a no op. You don't really gain anything from attempting to do it in parallel.

Comment: @Cubic I was under the impression it should allocate parts of the list to different threads so there would be effectively less ops per thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `parMap` sparks a parallel computation for each individual list element.  It doesn't chunk the list at all as you seem to think from your comments—that would require the use of the [`parListChunk`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parallel-3.2.1.0/docs/Control-Parallel-Strategies.html#v:parListChunk) strategy.

So `parMap` has high overheads, so the fact that each spark simply squares one number means that its cost is overwhelmed by that overhead.

Comment: Squaring is so cheap that I would guess the list splitting in `parListChunk` also overwhelms the parallel gains.

Comment: Plus paralellization kills fusion, which would otherwise yield orders of magnitude speedup.

Comment: @AndrásKovács: Indeed.  When [I parallelized a program of mine](https://github.com/sacundim/tau-sigma/pull/18) (using `parBuffer`, however) I observed precisely that sort of thing. The program computes a family of statistical functions over input data, and some much more expensive than others. So it made the fast ones a bit slower at the cost of making the slow ones much faster. With minimal effort.